# Best-fit Parabolic or quartic equation from data points

Tags: conic-sections, curves

I need to find an equation for a parabola or quartic equation that approximates my data points. (*points do not fall on the exact parabola.*)

for example my data is : `{194, 267, 415, 553, 803, 923, 1139, 1159, 1357, 1537, 1457, 1591, 1681, 1591, 1457, 1537, 1357, 1159, 1139, 923, 803, 553, 415, 267, 194}`

Comment: Results by [Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=bestfit%20194%2C%20267%2C%20415%2C%20553%2C%20803%2C%20923%2C%201139%2C%201159%2C%201357%2C%201537%2C%201457%2C%201591%2C%201681%2C%201591%2C%201457%2C%201537%2C%201357%2C%201159%2C%201139%2C%20923%2C%20803%2C%20553%2C%20415%2C%20267%2C%20194)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4415104/formula-for-coefficients-of-least-squares-regression-quad/4415184#4415184 for the formula

Comment: First, you have to decide what you mean by "best-fit".

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP doesn't communicate.